# Name 'event' can be undefined but event is clearly defined

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game from a tutorial I found on Youtube and then I come across this error that I cannot fix. I keep getting the error message: Name 'event' can be undefined. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Here is my full code:

> ```
> import pygame
> from sys import exit
>
> def display_score():
>     current_time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000) - start_time
>     score_surf = test_font.render(f'{current_time}', False, (64, 64, 64))
>     score_rect = score_surf.get_rect(center=(400, 50))
>     screen.blit(score_surf, score_rect)
>
> pygame.init()
> screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
> pygame.display.set_caption('Runner')
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> test_font = pygame.font.Font('Pixeltype.ttf', 50)
> game_active = True
> start_time = 0
>
> sky_surf = pygame.image.load('Sky.png').convert()
> ground_surf = pygame.image.load('ground.png').convert()
>
> snail_surf = pygame.image.load('snail1.png').convert_alpha()
> snail_rect = snail_surf.get_rect(bottomright=(600, 300))
>
> player_surf = pygame.image.load('player_walk_1.png').convert_alpha()
> player_rect = player_surf.get_rect(midbottom=(80, 300))
> player_gravity = 0
>
> while True:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>             pygame.quit()
>             exit()
>
>         if game_active:
>             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>                 if player_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and player_rect.bottom >= 300:
>                     player_gravity = -20
>
>         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
>             if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and player_rect.bottom >= 300:
>                 player_gravity = -20
>     else:
>         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
>             game_active = True
>             start_time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000)
>
>     if game_active:
>         screen.blit(sky_surf, (0, 0))
>         screen.blit(ground_surf, (0, 300))
>         
>         display_score()
>         snail_rect.x -= 4
>         if snail_rect.right <= 0: snail_rect.left = 800
>         screen.blit(player_surf, player_rect)
>
>         # Player
>         player_gravity += 1
>         player_rect.y += player_gravity
>         if player_rect.bottom >= 300: player_rect.bottom = 300
>         screen.blit(snail_surf, snail_rect)
>
>         # Collision
>         if snail_rect.colliderect(player_rect):
>             game_active = False
>
>     else:
>         screen.fill((94, 129, 162))
>
>     pygame.display.update()
>     clock.tick(60)
> ```
>
> It's quite clear I have the variable 'event' defined in the while loop using the get function.
>
> ```
> while True:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
>             pygame.quit()
>             exit()
>
>         if game_active:
>             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>                 if player_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and player_rect.bottom >= 300:
>                     player_gravity = -20
>
>         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
>             if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and player_rect.bottom >= 300:
>                 player_gravity = -20
>     else:
>         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
>             game_active = True
>             start_time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000)
> ```

This is the snippet of the code where the problem is:

Basically, what this else statement is supposed to do is to restart the game when clicked space bar. But it doesn't work because apparently the name event is not defined.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
```

The weird thing is, is that I am only getting the error message specifically for this line of code and not any other code that has event.type in it. I believe it has something to do with this else statement and that's why it is not working. I deleted this else statement to see what would happen and the error message went away but it still won't work.

1. I tried reformatting the code, changing things around, indenting and unindenting, and etc. I tried re-pasting pygame.event.get(): into the else statement. Nothing worked.

Comment: Suppose there weren't any events. The `else` would run but `event` would not have been assigned.

Comment: at the line in question, the `else:` block is at the indentation level of the preceding `for:` loop, which means it will execute if the for loop completes due to exhausting its iterable without a `break` or `return` or `exit()` bring called within the loop. Therefore, that line only runs after all events have been processed (or if there weren't any) and event may be `None`.  Maybe you meant it to be an `elif:` with the preceding `if:` when `game_active == False`?. Not clear as you have space bar both to do the in game action and to restart.